# Running javafx cross-platform .jar on ubuntu

Tags: maven, ubuntu, javafx, jar

I created cross-platform .jar file with maven shade plugin. This jar works fine on windows, but when I try to run it on ubuntu I get an Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:42)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:145)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:281)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:288)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:160)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:661)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:681)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Failed to load Glass factory class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.createApplication()" because the return value of "com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory()" is null
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:145)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:281)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:288)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:160)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:661)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:681)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have installed gtk:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

...and openjfx:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

...but it didn't help.

my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sudoku</groupId>
    <artifactId>mega_sudoku</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>mega_sudoku</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>


        <!-- openjfx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>mega_sudoku.main.JarLauncher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <finalName>mega_sudoku</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

java --version:

```
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Is this problem with my .jar, or I need to do smth with my ubuntu jdk configuration?
How can I solve this problem? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by adding this dependencies to pom.xml

```
        <!-- media -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>


        <!-- graphics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17-ea+11</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
```